# Is it ok to place help icon inside modal windows? Is there is any UX reason that this would not work?

Tags: modal-windows, context-sensitive-help

[image: example]

I have a Scenario, were I need to place help icon inside a modal window, Even though I have help icon on screen i.e... behind modal window. Is it is ok to have Help icon inside modal window, If not is there is any good reason for not to have that inside modal window.

Comment: You can place icons wherever you like. But I sense the question is more about what happens when you *select* the help icon, yes? Are you asking if it is OK to trigger a modal from within another modal?

Comment: Yes exactly, Is it good to open an modal window over the modal window or I can try opening the help information in a new window.

Comment: In that case your question may be a duplicate of this one: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/46261/modals-on-top-of-modals. Does that one answer your question?