# Browse to updaload image from modal dialog

Tags: usability, interaction-design, interface

I know modal over a modal  is not good UX. But I have a modal window and I am going to place a file upload(browse) component to upload a image for user. I am not really sure, will that break any UX by opening up the second dialog (window) to browse a file? Any suggestions, should I do or do not? Appreciate your comments.
NOTE: This is not the modal over another modal, it is modal over a system file upload popup.

Comment: Please check this thread. http://ux.stackexchange.com/q/46261/97647 I hope it answers you well

Comment: Thanks for all  your answers/comments, my situation is different. Its not that I have two modals, it is just one modal and system popup. The link says modal over a modal which is different and I understand that too.

Comment: It's essentially the same thing, @NPN. That system prompt is modal in nature.

Answer (score 0):

I think that will not going to be a problem if you are not going more than 2 model windows in single page.  As far as your page concern, you will be having one model window and another possibly system file browser window.  We can have it from my perception.

Comment: My concern is, Does user feel system popup as a modal or not in this situation?

Comment: As far as my understanding, user would not confuse the system window (i.e. file browser window) with custom model popup windows.  This is not only my gut feeling, I have had real time user experience in this scenarios.